# Symfony: retrieve route parameter in 'updateAction'

Tags: php, symfony

I use the following route in my controller A:

```
@Route("/title/{title}", name="Title")
```

I have a function called `TitleAction` that has `$request` and `$title` as parameters. This function returns the page with data. I use the `{title}` to retrieve data from the db.

On the page I have a filter which calls an ajax call to another function in my controller (where `TitleAction` is also located). The function retrieves some data from the db and returns a json response to my ajax call. Is there any way to also retrieve that {title} parameter for this function?

I tried with `@route` and `$request->get..` but no result.

UPDATE:

title.html.twig:

```
<select id="filter1">
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    {% for c in cs %}
        <option value="{{ c.name }}">{{ c.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="filter2">
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    {% for g in gs %}
        <option value="{{ g.name }}">{{ g.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

{% if results.low != 0 %}
    <p class="amount" id="low">{{ results.low|round(0, 'floor') }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p class="amount">N/A</p>
{% endif %}
```

AJAX call in javascript file (I only copied one function of the filter since the other one is a copy but with filter2:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#filter1").change(function() {
        var inputCS = $(this).val();
        if(inputCs.length >= 1) {
            var data = {inputCS: inputCS};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ROOT_URL + "default/update/data",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 3000,
                success: function(results){
                    //some innerHTML replacements
                  if(result.low === null) {
                     document.getElementById("low").innerHTML = 'N/A'
                  }
                  else {
                     document.getElementById("low").innerHTML = 
                     Math.floor(Number(result.result.low));
                  }
                },
                error: function() {
                   //
                }
            })
        }


    });
})
```

DefaultController:

```
**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}


/**
* @Route("/title/{title}", name="Title")
* @param Request $request
* @param $title
* @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
*/
public function TitleAction(Request $request, $title)
{



    //Some DB calls to retrieve data with 'where .. = $title'
    return $this->render('default/title.html.twig', array(
            'title' => $title,
            'results' => $results[0],
            'cs' => $cs,
            'gs' => $gs,

            ...
            }
}



/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function updateDataAction(Request $request)
{


        //Here I also want to use $title so I can use it in my query

        $dataCS = $request->get('inputCS');
        $dataGS = $request->get('inputGS');

        if(!empty($dataGS) and !empty($dataCS)) {
            // $results = Query
        } 
        else {
            // $results = Query

        }

        return new JsonResponse(array('results' => $results[0]));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you send over that variable as parameter to that function?

Comment: I was unable to retrieve it from the URL. Maybe I did something wrong and I wasn' sure if I needed to use a regex since there could be blanks.. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the "title" as a query parameter to your updateDataAction() method
first, declare some var someTitle in your template, like this :

```
<script>var someTitle = "{{ $title }}"; </script>
```

then, you can reference the someTitle variable in your javascript file, and use it as a query parameter in you js file :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#filter1").change(function() {
    var inputCS = $(this).val();
    if(inputCs.length >= 1) {
        var data = {inputCS: inputCS, title: someTitle};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ROOT_URL + "default/update/data",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function(results){
                //some innerHTML replacements
              if(result.low === null) {
                 document.getElementById("low").innerHTML = 'N/A'
              }
              else {
                 document.getElementById("low").innerHTML = 
                 Math.floor(Number(result.result.low));
              }
            },
            error: function() {
               //
            }
        })
    }


});
```

})

Finally, you can get the title inside your updateDataAction() method :

```
public function updateDataAction(Request $request)
{
    // Here I also want to use $title so I can use it in my query
    $title = $request->query->get('title');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That did it, ty.

Answer (score 1):

In your `default/title.html.twig` file, you can reference your route like so:

```
{{ path('Title',{'title': val.getTitle}) }}
```

where `title` (in lower case) is the parameter being passed in to the route, and then `val` is what you set in array to pass to twig, and getTitle is just a getter.

I'm not sure if this will help with your AJAX call, but it may be easier to make the call in Twig. You can read up more on that in my article here: 
https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/specify-route-with-parameters-in-twig/

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: "I'm not sure if this will help with your AJAX call, but it may be easier to make the call in Twig."

So here you mean that I can route to my controller with the above path and there do an AJAX call to retrieve the values from my filters? The page has two filters (using the `<select><option></option></select>`)

Comment: Is it possible to post some example code so I can see what you are trying to do? Right now I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I've updated my original comment with a code example. I hope it gives a bit more background information on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your code enough to give a good response in the comments. It is a good question and you've posted a lot of details, so I upvoted your question. Maybe you need to ask the question in a different way. You can always post another question(s).

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that